# DRF Api-Key missing Attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use the DRF Api Key mechanism for authentication, after following the guide here:
https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/

I receive nothing but errors, does someone have a working example or see what i am doing wrong here?

Global Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':  [
        'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey'
    ]
}
```

Tested in a class view also

````
class TestingApiKey(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated | HasAPIKey]
    def post(self, request):```
````

3 sample curl requests:

Example 1

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test' \
--header 'Authorization: Api-Key TiJwEHau.MF4ov6E3iz3C9KNNRAGdryH1tXfkjz8r' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username" : "Testing",
    "Password"    : "Testing123"
    }'
```

Example 2:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test' \
--header 'Api-Key TiJwEHau.MF4ov6E3iz3C9KNNRAGdryH1tXfkjz8r' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username" : "Testing",
    "Password"    : "Testing123"
    }'
```

Example 3

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test' \
--header 'X-Api-Key: Api-Key TiJwEHau.MF4ov6E3iz3C9KNNRAGdryH1tXfkjz8r' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username" : "Testing",
    "Password"    : "Testing123"
    }'
```

Each test I carry out returns a 500 server error with the response:

```
'HasAPIKey' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
```

Anyone had this issue or understand why I would get this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this has to do with adding global settings in the settings.py file.

I went back and commented out the following in the settings.py

```
"""
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':  [,
        'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey'
    ]
}
"""
```

Once done I then added the following class object and everything worked fine.

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated | HasAPIKey]
```